# Select a specific row from Data Table

Tags: c#

So I have a datatable and I'm using linq to get a specific row and then I want to loop over the row.

```
var table = myTable.AsEnumerable();
var myRow = table.Where(x => x.Field<int>("Year") == 2018);

 foreach (DataRow row in myRow.Table.Rows)
 {
     //print row 
 }
```

However, it seems like myRow still contains all the rows. How do I get only the specific row that should results from that linq query and loop over it? I guess what i want is array of the resulting row. The resulting row contains a combination of different types including strings, ints and decimals.

I have tried

```
DataRow myRow2 = table.FirstOrDefault();
```

still the same result.

Answer (score 3):

You actually just want the following for the foreach:

```
foreach (DataRow row in myRows)
```

When you have the result of your query, accessing the Table is actually pointing back to the unfiltered table, and returning all the rows associated with it.

Comment: results in foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'DatRow' because does not contain a public instance definition of 'getEnumerator'."

Comment: update: mybad. I had firstordefault() at the end of linq query . Thanks. It worked.

Comment: @CaesarTex That makes sense, the only reason that `myRows.Table.Rows` would have worked is if you'd already selected a single row, then jumped up to it's containing table to grab all of it's rows.

Answer (score 1):

You should loop over the result of the Where.
Where returns an enumerable of DataRow(s), so it is more appropriate the plural.

```
var myRows = table.Where(x => x.Field<int>("Year") == 2018);
foreach (DataRow row in myRows)
{
    //print row 
}
```

Where also doesn't filter the current table, so your code loops over the full row collection.

Another way to get a filtered set of your rows is through the Select native method. Not sure which is better in perfomances.

```
var myRows = table.Select("Year = 2018");
foreach (DataRow row in myRow.Table.Rows)
{
   //print row 
}
```

Comment: I tried that but it gives "foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'DatRow' because does not contain a public instance definition of 'getEnumerator'."

Comment: You were right. it worked. I just had firstordefault() at the end of linq messing it up.